# Overloading Method To Allow Adding It As Event Handler?

Tags: c#, events, overloading

I'm overloading a method so it can be assigned to an event.  There has to be a better way to do this.

```
myMethod(){
    //Does some stuff...
}
myMethod(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
    myMethod();
}

Form.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(myMethod);
```

Comment: @pst how would that help? Overload resolution isn't an issue here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An anonymous method works well here:

```
form.FormClosing += delegate { myMethod(); };
```

The compiler pretty much does what you did, but with less plumbing code to read.